# How can I change my abstract font to text terminal (texttt) including the section title "Abstract"

Tags: abstract, typewriter

I have a document with an abstract.

```
\begin{abstract}

    \texttt{
        blaa blaa
    }

\end{abstract}
```

The abstract text appears as texttt as expected.

How can I make the heading, i.e., the text which says "Abstract" appear in `texttt` font also?

Comment: This depends on the document class, but `\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\texttt{Abstract}}` should do, if the `titlepage` option isn't used

Comment: `{\ttfamily\begin{abstract} content \end{abstract}}`  Note the exra pair of braces around the whole construct.

Comment: Please note that `ttfamily` or `\texttt` is not capable of hyphenation.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a `etoolbox` way, switching to `ttfamily` right at the start of the `abstract` environment.

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{abstract}{%
\ttfamily%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
  Brontosaurs are thin at one end, thick in the middle and thin at the other end.
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

[image]